# Infotec X4 on Ubuntu with NUT

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ups

I am trying to connect an Infotec X4 UPS to NUT on an Ubuntu server.

The UPS is correctly recognized by ViewPower software on a Windows laptop. This allowed me to conclude that the USB interface works (and that the ViewPower software with this UPS delivers significantly inferior information when compared to all other sofware I have used in the past).

The ViewPower software on Linux does run, but does not recognize the UPS.

Searching on the NUT mailing list has found a few other people with the same symptoms, but when the configuration is the same as mine, the threads stop with no definite answer (in my experience, this pattern is usually associated with some very simple 'gotcha').

My NUT ups.conf specifies,

```
[infosec]
desc      = "Infosec X4 UPS"
driver    = blazer_usb
subdriver = cypress
vendorid  = 0665
productid = 5161
port      = auto
```

`lsusb` does recognize the device:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 0665:5161 Cypress Semiconductor USB to Serial
```

and `dmesg` reports,

```
[66517.240529] usb 1-2: new low-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[66517.373937] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0665, idProduct=5161
[66517.373946] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[66517.373952] usb 1-2: Product: USB to Serial
[66517.373957] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: INNO TECH
[66517.379526] hid-generic 0003:0665:5161.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.00 Device [INNO TECH USB to Serial] on usb-0000:00:14.0-2/input0
```

Unfortunately, no driver appears to work with NUT:

```
# /lib/nut/blazer_usb -DDD -a infosec

Network UPS Tools - Megatec/Q1 protocol USB driver 0.11 (2.7.2)

   0.000000     debug level is '3'
   ...
   0.109923     Device matches
   0.110537     Trying megatec protocol...
   0.111098     send: Q1
   1.111366     read: error sending control message: Operation not permitted
   1.111394     blazer_status: short reply
   1.111407     Status read 1 failed
   1.111950     send: Q1
   1.241571     read: N
   1.241599     blazer_status: short reply
   1.241612     Status read 2 failed
   1.242154     send: Q1
   1.372572     read: N
   1.372600     blazer_status: short reply
   1.372613     Status read 3 failed
```

The other protocols also fail (megatec/old, mustek, and zinto).

In the man page for `nutdrv_qx` I found (emphasis mine):

> *SUPPORTED HARDWARE*
>
> The nutdrv_qx driver is known to work with various UPSes from Blazer, Energy Sistem, Fenton Technologies, General Electric, Mustek,
> Voltronic Power
> (rebranded by many, many - have I said many? - others.. Long story short: **if your UPS came with a software called Viewpower, chances are high that it works with this driver with one of the voltronic* protocols or with the newer one**) and many others.

I have tried `nutdrv_qx`, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## A newer NUT was required.

Having at last found [a promising hint](https://alioth-lists.debian.net/pipermail/nut-upsuser/2016-October/010315.html) that the Voltronic protocol is being updated, I downloaded and compiled 2.7.4. It reported recognizing the Voltronic-QS-Hex 0.10 protocol. So:

```
[infosec]
desc      = "Infosec X4 UPS"
driver    = nutdrv_qx
protocol  = Voltronic-QS-Hex
vendorid  = 0665
productid = 5161
port      = auto
```